# How to stretch one of the TableRow's children to the maximum available height?

Tags: flutter

Code:

```dart
Table(
  children: [
    TableRow(
      children: [
        Container(height: 100, color: Colors.red),
        Container(color: Colors.green), // Read 'Q1' below. 
        Container(height: 100, color: Colors.blue),
      ],
    ),
  ],
)
```

**Q1:** How to stretch green Container height to the maximum height of the given `TableRow`?

---

PS: For simplicity, I provided manual heights to the container1 and the container2 but in real world, I don't know their heights. Second, I know I can find the height of both the Container using `RenderBox` and then I can find out the max of (container1, container3) and apply that to the 2nd one but that would be too much of work, I'm looking for a better approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [TableCell](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TableCell-class.html) and [TableCellVerticalAlignment.fill](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/TableCellVerticalAlignment-class.html).

`TableCell`:

> A widget that controls how a child of a Table is aligned.
> A TableCell widget must be a descendant of a Table, and the path from the TableCell widget to its enclosing Table must contain only TableRows, StatelessWidgets, or StatefulWidgets (not other kinds of widgets, like RenderObjectWidgets).

`TableCellVerticalAlignment.fill`:

> Cells with this alignment are sized to be as tall as the row, then made to fit the row.`If all the cells have this alignment, then the row will have zero height.`

```dart
Table(
  children: [
    TableRow(
      children: [
        Container(height: 100, color: Colors.red),
        TableCell(
          verticalAlignment: TableCellVerticalAlignment.fill,
          child: Container(color: Colors.green),
        ),
        Container(height: 100, color: Colors.blue),
      ],
    ),
  ],
)
```